# Ad Targeting - Find Entities by URNs API ClassCastException error message

Tags: linkedin-api

I have some problem with the ["Find Entities by URNs"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/advertising-targeting/ads-targeting#find-entities-by-urns) API in order to retrieve the metadata and value information for a collection of URNs.

If I use the URL described in the doc ([Sample request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/advertising-targeting/ads-targeting#unencoded-sample-request)) with a valid access token:

`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adTargetingEntities?q=urns&urns=List(urn%3Ali%3AfieldOfStudy%3A100990,urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A1035,urn%3Ali%3Aseniority%3A9)&locale=(language:en,country:US)&oauth2_access_token=<a-valid-token>`

I receive the message:

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 0,
    "message": "java.lang.ClassCastException",
    "status": 500
}
```

Anyone have experience the same issue? Any idea how to fix it?

Also: how can i contact for technical support as in this case?

**UPDATE:**

I made some try and I fix using the following version:

`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adTargetingEntities?q=urns&urns=urn%3Ali%3AfieldOfStudy%3A100990&urns=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A1035&urns=urn%3Ali%3Aseniority%3A9&locale.language=it&locale.country=IT&oauth2_access_token=<a-valid-token>`

BUT the locale/language translation is not working. Could be this a working solutions?

Comment: Submit a request to linkedin.zendesk.com

Comment: thanks @ChristopherOu I haven't any valid link to zendesk for linkedin. If I try to open the http://linkedin.zendesk.com link I will redirect to an error page (seems about oauth problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the support team:

> Our docs are missing 1 critical piece of information. Whenever using
>   LIST and encoded URNs in the URL, we expect an additional header `'x-restli-protocol-version: 2.0.0'`
>
> The correct API call would be Request:
>
> ```
> curl -X GET \
> 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adTargetingEntities?q=urns&urns=List(urn%3Ali%3Aindustry%3A1,urn%3Ali%3Aseniority%3A9)&locale=(language:it,country:IT)'
> \
> -H 'x-restli-protocol-version: 2.0.0' \
> -H 'Authorization: Bearer <Token>'
> ```
>
> Response:
>
> ```
> {
>     "elements": [
>         {
>             "facetUrn": "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:industries",
>             "name": "Difesa e spazio",
>             "urn": "urn:li:industry:1"
>         },
>         {
>             "facetUrn": "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:seniorities",
>             "name": "Partner",
>             "urn": "urn:li:seniority:9"
>         }
>     ],
>     "paging": {
>         "count": 2147483647,
>         "links": [],
>         "start": 0
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Yes, it does provide a response in locale.

Hope this can help other guys in the future