# LinkedIn API: Server error while listing UGC posts

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm getting a server error when trying to list all UGC posts for an organization.

I have followed the API documentation there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api#find-ugc-posts-by-authors

I'm doing a GET request on this URL: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List(urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A6645672)

I added the Authorization header with the correct value.

The UGC posts should be returned, but instead I'm getting the following API response:

```json
{
  'serviceErrorCode': 0,
  'message': 'java.lang.ClassCastException',
  'status': 500
}
```

And here are the response headers:

```json
{
  'X-LI-ResponseOrigin': 'RGW',
  'X-Restli-Gateway-Error': 'true',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Content-Length': '76',
  'X-Li-Fabric': 'prod-lor1',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'X-Li-Pop': 'prod-efr5',
  'X-LI-Proto': 'http/1.1',
  'X-LI-UUID': 'lsI6Y1fvpRUgJP1JhSsAAA==',
  'Set-Cookie': 'lidc="b=OB36:g=1813:u=339:i=1559916004:t=1559978523:s=AQE_uyAgsS2aohUoPQqxLGIDiYC9Gpfr"',
  'X-LI-Route-Key': '"b=OB36:g=1813:u=339:i=1559916004:t=1559978523:s=AQE_uyAgsS2aohUoPQqxLGIDiYC9Gpfr"'
}
```

For privacy reasons I'm not giving you the Access Token, but your team will have all the details with the request ID present in the response headers I just pasted above.

Thanks to the community or LinkedIn support team to help me debugging this error.

Best regards.

Comment: Hi! IS not clear if in your request you add the required header: All API requests are represented in protocol 2.0.0 and require the header `X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the note of the doc you refer:

> All API requests are represented in protocol 2.0.0 and require the
>   header `X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0`.

You should add the header in the request, as example, the following request went fine:

```
curl -H "X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0" "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List(urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A6645672)&oauth2_access_token=<a-valid-token>
```

Hope this help

Comment: Hi @Matteo,

my problem was solved by adding the header `X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0`. Thanks for your help.

Please note that other API endpoints seems to work without this header, e.g. `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls`... probably because this API endpoint already exist on prior API version.

And while reverse engineering some informations (like the permissions needed to do some API calls), I forgot the essential: API requests basics (I mean setting this header).

Comment: Hi @mykel I experience the same problem with another API and solve with that header, you can find the response of the CS in my auto-answered question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56222238/ad-targeting-find-entities-by-urns-api-classcastexception-error-message

Comment: Hi @mykel if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thanks @Matteo, I'm a Stack Overflow newbie and thought that my reputation was too low to mark your comment as the solution 